# Swiper Js - Can't remove overlay linear background from image post

Tags: swiper.js

I'm working with Swiper JS. I integrated it with Wordpress, and it is working fine except for the gray linear-background overlay effect that I don't know how to remove, because it is generated by JS on-the-fly and cannot be removed by css class alone.

The code in question:

```
element.style {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(55, 64, 71, 0.3), rgba(55, 64, 71, 0.3)), url(https://nwinteriordesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/bathroom-design.jpg);
```

I need that linear-gradient gone. Any help appreciated. Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Uma.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I get it resolved. It seems to be an issue with Wordpress post not swipe js